# Jenkins Pipeline Multibranch doesn't run post steps if there is merge conflicts

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a multibranch pipeline with the following behaviors:
[image: Multibranch pipeline behaviors]

And the following Jenkinsfile:

```
 pipeline {
     agent {
         label 'apple'
     }

     stages {
         stage('Lint') {
             when {
                 changeRequest()
             }

             steps {
                 sh 'fastlane lint'
             }
         }
     }

     post {
         success {
             reportSuccess()
         }

         failure {
             reportFailure()
         }
     }
 }
```

I use a slave to run the actual build, but the master still needs to checkout the code to get the Jenkinsfile. For that, it seems to use the same behaviors as the one defined in the job even though it really only needs the Jenkinsfile.

My problem is that I want to discover pull requests by *merging the pull request with the current target branch revision*, but when there is a merge conflict the build will fail before the Jenkinsfile is executed. This prevents any kind of reporting done in post steps.

Is there a way to have the initial checkout not merge the target branch, but still have it merged when actually running the Jenkinsfile on a slave?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out using "Current Pull Request revision" strategy, and then on a successful build issue a `git merge` command.